# Coin streak not working. Is it because of the nested ifs?

Tags: python

Trying to calculate Head or Tails streaks in 100 coin flips, but I am getting weird results in the streaks number. Could you please help me understand why?

Here is the code:

```
import random
numberOfStreaks = 0
streakCounter = 0


headOrTail = []

for coinFlip in range(101):
    result = random.randint(0,1)
    headOrTail.append(result)

print (headOrTail)

for i in headOrTail:
    if headOrTail[i]==headOrTail[i-1]:
        streakCounter +=1
        if streakCounter == 6:
            numberOfStreaks += 1
            streakCounter = 0

    else:
        streakCounter = 0



print(numberOfStreaks)
```

Comment: "Weird results" is not a specific problem. Show your _actual_ results, and describe how it differs from expected results, as part of the question.

Comment: Even better would be to ask a _reproducible_ question with, f/e, a specific set of integers being read from, so there's a specific expected correct answer you can ask why your code doesn't return. See [mre] guidelines.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking your time to explain the correct way to post my questions.

Comment: The "weird" result I get is from the list line: print(numberOfStreaks), which should print how many times I get a streak of either 6 heads or tails in the list headOrTails, but the results I get are never correct if I count the heads and tails in that list

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably with the `for`-loop.  You probably want to say:

```py
for i in range(len(headOrTail)):
    if headOrTail[i] == headOrTail[i-1]:
        ...
```

To be a bit more specific: if you have a list and iterate through it using a for-loop, the for-loop takes the elements inside the list, not the indices as in most other programming languages.  I.e. Python's `for`-loop is actuall a `for each`-loop.

Compare:

```py
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
for p in primes:
    print(p)        # prints 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13

for i in range(len(primes)):
    print(i)        # prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

A good way to iterate with an index in Python is by using `enumerate`, which combines both:

```py
for i,p in enumerate(primes):
    print("The %dth prime is: %d" % (i, p))
```

Comment: There's a `)` missing to close the `range` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I just want to go through the headOrTail list and check how many streaks of 6 heads or tail are in there